# Custom readLine

Tags: java, newline

I need to implement custom readLine method, with the following signature:

```
public String readLine(int maxLineLength)
```

So I've created:

```
public String readLine(int maxLineLength) throws ReadingLineException {

    if (this.eofReached){
        return null;
    }

    StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder();

    try {

        int readCount = 0;

        int charCode;
        while ((charCode = this.readable.read()) > -1
                    || readCount <= maxLineLength) {
            readCount += 1;
            bld.append((char)charCode);
        }

        if (readCount > maxLineLength){
            throw new ReadingLineException("Maximum line length reached.");
        }

        if (charCode == -1) {
            this.eofReached = true;
        }

        return bld.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ReadingLineException();
    }
}
```

So.. How can i detect end of line using only `read`? I don't think it could be simple

```
(char)charCode == '\n'
```

because it could not work in other system (where EOL is marked as `\n\r`)

I though to read additional char after `\n` and the determine if it is `\r`, -1 or other char. If it would '\r' then I've reached EOL and everything is OK, when -1 the same case but when it would be other char, then I'd start with it on the next readLine. Is it proper way?

Comment: you can check the implementation of [`BufferReader#realLine`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/BufferedReader.java#BufferedReader.readLine%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just ignore '\r'. if char is '\r', read another.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
while ((charCode = this.readable.read()) > -1 || readCount <= maxLineLength)
```

This already doesn't make sense. The tests are back to front, you're using the wrong comparison operator, and you're using the wrong logical operator. At present this loop forces you to read and store EOS several times until `maxLineLength` is attained. It should be more like this:

```
while (readCount < maxLineLength && (charCode = this.readable.read()) > -1)
```

Second:

```
if (readCount > maxLineLength) {
        throw new ReadingLineException("Maximum line length reached.");
    }
```

I don't see how you can possibly throw this exception once you've fixed the above bug. You need to decide whether you're going to stop reading when you hit the maximum, or throw an exception. This code exhibits nothing but confusion about that.

Third: There is no attempt here to stop at a line terminator. `BufferedReader.readLine()` stops at any of `\r`, `\n`, or `\r\n`, which takes a bit of doing, as you have to peek after `\r` to see if the next char is `\n`, and push it back if it isn't.

> where EOL is marked as `\n\r`

There is no such system. You mean `\r\n`.

Fourth: if `eofReached` is true you should only return `sb.toString()` if it is of non-zero length. Otherwise you should return `null.`

Keep trying.

Comment: First: yeah, you are right - I've just wrote Unit Tests so I've already dected that bug.
Second: Exception will stay. It's protection for too long data. I don't want to process part of string (up to maxLineLength)
Third: yeah, I've done it like 'jeukku' said. If it's going about `\n\r` - my bad, wrong order.
Fourth: no, I'll return null. I will use that readLine multiple times, so `null` indicates me the moment, when there is no more lines to read from input.